# Kernel module inconsistency

Tags: drivers, kernel-modules, udev

everyone.

I have special USB device (chinese touchscreen), what I need to connect to my computer with Linux.

By default, Linux assign connected device to **usbhid** (I found this info by execute **usb-devices** and node **hidraw*** appears after connecting touchscreen to computer) kernel module, so my system can't see touchscreen as input device. Also, I have drivers for this device. I build and install driver into my Linux system, and create instructions to load this module at system startup in **/etc/modules-load.d/**.

Driver loaded successfully at startup (I get this info by execute **lsmod**), but touchscreen still attached to **usbhid**. I know that driver works well because if I unload **usbhid** and replug device, touchscreen driver capture touchscreen.

```
[alarm@alarmpi ~]$ usb-devices 

T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=03 Cnt=02 Dev#=  4 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0eef ProdID=0005 Rev=02.00
S:  Manufacturer=RPI_TOUCH
S:  Product=By ZH851
S:  SerialNumber=RÿhgWUC`g
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=c0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=(usbhid)
```

I found that there is a way to unbind device from **usbhid** by creating udev rule. So, here is my udev rule:

```
ATTRS{idVendor}=="0eef", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0005", DRIVER=="usbhid", RUN="/bin/sh -c 'echo -n $kernel > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usbhid/unbind'"
```

After computer reboot, **usb-devices** show me that touchscreen has no attached drivers at all!!! I think, my driver will capture it:

```
[alarm@alarmpi ~]$ usb-devices 

T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=03 Cnt=02 Dev#=  4 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0eef ProdID=0005 Rev=02.00
S:  Manufacturer=RPI_TOUCH
S:  Product=By ZH851
S:  SerialNumber=RÿhgWUC`g
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=c0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=(none)
```

Ok, I also find that **sysfs** provides **new_id** field in my driver. Googling for **new_id** in **sys_fs** I found what if I send vendor and product IDs to it, device will be binded to driver and driver will capture device. So, If I execute at shell something like this:

```
[alarm@alarmpi ~]# echo -n 0eef 0005 > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/eleduino_ts/new_id
```

Everything works as I need. So, I decide to update my udev rule with this string:

```
# 1. Unbind our device from usbhid:
ATTRS{idVendor}=="0eef", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0005", DRIVER=="usbhid", RUN="/bin/sh -c 'echo -n $kernel > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/usbhid/unbind'"

# 2. Bind device to eleduino_ts driver:
ATTRS{idVENDOR}=="0eef", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0005", RUN="/bin/sh -c 'echo -n '0eef 0005' > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/eleduino_ts/new_id'"
```

Apply new udev rule, reboot, execute usb-device:

[alarm@alarmpi ~]$ usb-devices

```
T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=03 Cnt=02 Dev#=  4 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0eef ProdID=0005 Rev=02.00
S:  Manufacturer=RPI_TOUCH
S:  Product=By ZH851
S:  SerialNumber=RÿhgWUC`g
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=c0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=(usbhid)
```

What's going on? Why **usbhid**?.

Well, I decide to downgrade udev rule and create **system.d** service. Here is it:

```
[alarm@alarmpi ~]$ cat /etc/systemd/system/eleduino_ts.service 
[Unit]
Description=Bind device to eleduinos_ts
Conflicts=getty@tty1.service plymouth-quit.service
After=systemd-user-sessions.service getty@tty1.service plymouth-quit.service

[Service]
ExecStart=/bin/echo -n 0eef 0005 > /sys/bus/usb/drivers/eleduino_ts/new_id
Restart=always
IgnoreSIGPIPE=no

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.targets
```

I know, that service executes well, but my touchscreen still has no attached drivers:

```
[alarm@alarmpi ~]$ usb-devices 

T:  Bus=01 Lev=02 Prnt=02 Port=03 Cnt=02 Dev#=  4 Spd=12  MxCh= 0
D:  Ver= 2.00 Cls=00(>ifc ) Sub=00 Prot=00 MxPS=64 #Cfgs=  1
P:  Vendor=0eef ProdID=0005 Rev=02.00
S:  Manufacturer=RPI_TOUCH
S:  Product=By ZH851
S:  SerialNumber=RÿhgWUC`g
C:  #Ifs= 1 Cfg#= 1 Atr=c0 MxPwr=100mA
I:  If#= 0 Alt= 0 #EPs= 2 Cls=03(HID  ) Sub=00 Prot=00 Driver=(none)
```

So, my question is: How can I attach my driver to my device?

P.S. Maybe it will help:

```
[alarm@alarmpi ~]$ uname -a 
Linux alarmpi 4.1.12-1-ARCH #1 PREEMPT Tue Oct 27 19:16:04 MDT 2015 armv6l GNU/Linux
```

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I've asked this question in other threads, but nobody give me an answer.